# Async function call in REST API

Tags: go

Here I have one function i.e returnAllArticles which will be called for REST API and this function returns a list of articles and inside this function one async function i.e DoneAsync is being called. This aysnc function may take some time to process its own data. I want json value i.e all articles should be returned whether that async function is complete or not. Code I have pasted below

```
func returnAllArticles(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request){
    fmt.Println("Endpoint Hit: returnAllArticles")
    json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(Articles)
   
        val := DoneAsync()
    fmt.Println("Done is running ...")
    fmt.Println(<- val)

}

func DoneAsync() chan int {
    r := make(chan int)
    fmt.Println("Warming up ...")
    go func() {
        time.Sleep(3 * time.Second)
        r <- 1
        fmt.Println("Done ...")
    }()
    return r
}
func handleRequests() {
    myRouter := mux.NewRouter().StrictSlash(true)
    myRouter.HandleFunc("/articles", returnAllArticles);
   log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8080",myRouter))
}
```

But in my case json value is not returning until async func is done. I am not getting asynchronous features for that async function.

Answer (score 1):

This line will block until a value is written to `val`:

```
    fmt.Println(<- val)
```

So your `DoneAsync` function creates a goroutine that goes on to process something, and in the end writes to the `val` channel, but the handler that called it waits until something is written to that channel.

If you want the encoded result to be sent while you're doing this processing, you can when if the response handler implements `Flusher`, and flush it:

```
if f, ok:=w.(http.Flusher); ok {
   f.Flush()
}
```

Comment: I modified the code, will it work,   func returnAllArticles(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request){
    fmt.Println("Endpoint Hit: returnAllArticles")
 if f, ok := w.(http.Flusher); ok {
     f.Flush()
  } else {
     log.Println("Damn, no flush");
  }

    json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(Articles)
   
         DoneAsync()
 fmt.Println("Done is running ...")
 //fmt.Println(<- val)

} I am not printing the variable which is returning from DoneAsync() funcion and use Flusher.

Comment: This is impossible to read. You should flush after writing the JSON

Comment: I am not not printing the value of val and not accepting it from DoneAsync function. Just calling DoneAsync();  Is it ok?

Comment: If you call DoneAsync without reading from the channel it returns, you will leak goroutines. Those DoneAsync functions will never terminate.

Comment: if I store the return value  from DonsAsync() function into a variable like val then I must use it which I printed out. But if I print then it will wait for the completion of DonaeAsync() function. Then asynchronous features won't work.

Comment: Do you want to handler to return after you call DoneAsync? Create another goroutine to read from the channel.

Comment: No, actually I want handler return encoded result to the  client  while DoneAsync() function is running. Actually DoneAsync() function would do some db insertion it may take long time. So that handler should return the result otherwise user has to wait more to get the result.

Comment: It sounds like you don't need DoneAsync to use a channel at all. Have it create a goroutine and remove the channel, since it looks like you don't need that anyway

Comment: Actually I need one asynchronous function i.e DneAsync() and if I not use channel then how  DoneAsync() function can be called inside handler. Because When a new Goroutine is started, the goroutine call returns immediately. Unlike functions, the control does not wait for the Goroutine to finish executing.

Comment: You don't need a channel for goroutine execution. The new goroutine will execute asynchronously while the goroutine created the new one will simply continue without waiting. If you need to wait for a goroutine to finish, you don't need asncyrohous execution

Comment: If I do not use channel then I can not call DoneAsync() function because it will execute as a separate thread. The control returns immediately to the next line of code after the Goroutine call. The main Goroutine should be running for any other Goroutines to run. If the main Goroutine terminates then the program will be terminated and no other Goroutine will run. That is why to stop main goroutine in my case handler I am using channel.

Comment: This looks like an http handler. The main goroutine will not terminate until the HTTP server goes down.

Comment: Finally I found one solution that to call DoneAsync() function using go keyword inside handler.

Comment: You are still missing the point. Do you need to use that channel? It appears that you don't.

Comment: Yes. I do not need to use the channel. Thanks